# How can I find the max x value of a 2D implicit function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

For a project I'm working on I want to fill a 2 Dimensional space defined by some implicit function with evenly spaced points.

Since these functions will be randomly produced, I want to be able to start at a known point of the function and work from there. I've decided to start at the max x value but have been unsuccessful at calculating this mathematically or with python.

An example function that I'm currently working on is:

3sin(2x)cos(0.5y^2)−x^2−y^2+15=0

Which looks like the following (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2prio9v2kw):

[image: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2prio9v2kw]

Any help in how to calculate the max would be much appreciated as I'm quite new to python and a bit stuck :)

Comment: You should give us more information on how those functions are generated. Are your functions always the same (with different parameters) ? Are the point (0,0) always surrounded by the implicit function `f(x,y) = 0` ? Do you need a specific method for your specific kind of functions or a general method ?

Comment: Even if it looks like that an implicit function plotter is able to compute the exact solution, under the hood, the plot function simply compute an interval small enough that satisfied the equation.

Comment: Also found some evenly spaced points (without tolerance) is an almost impossible task (if the function can not be made explicit), because to find the distance between two points you need to know the position of all the intermediate points (and in your case there is an infinite number of intermediate points).